# return state of a checkbox and return 0 if unchecked

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have been finding interesting possible solutions to this, none speak to me clearly unfortunately.

What I have is a series of checkboxes that store the users preferences, so when the page populates I need to know the state of the checkbox so it can display the preference. Also I noticed that HTML doesnt return a value if the checkbox is not checked, well I need to store a 0 if it is not checked. So what is a good way to accomplish this? I am using just HTML and PHP

I have seen a few solutions and have some questions. First the code

```
<form action="TradingRules.php" method="post">
 <h2><legend>Entry Rules</legend></h2>
 <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="30minRule" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST["30minRule"]))        {     echo 'checked="checked" '; } ?>>30 Min Rule</label></p>  
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buyOnPocketPivot" value="1">Buy on Pocket Pivot</label></p> 
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buyEODonPPday" value="1">Buy EOD on PP Day</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buyOn10WeekLineTest" value="1">Buy on 10 week line Test (within 3%)</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="okBelow400k" value="1">Ok below 400k Average</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buyIfOthersAreBreakingOut" value="1">Buy if other are breaking out</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buyIfStockHasUnusualStrength" value="1">Buy if stock has unusual strength</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buyOnNon-breakoutVolume" value="1">Buy on non-breakout Volume</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buyOnGap" value="1">Buy on Gap</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="enableGapRules" value="1">Enable Gap Rules</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buy<1WeekBeforeEarnings" value="1">Buy < 1 week before earning</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buyOn3WeeksTight" value="1">Buy on 3 weeks tight</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buyOnHTF" value="1">Buy on HTF</label></p>
  <p><label> <input type="checkbox" name="buyOnPullbackToPivot" value="1">Buy on pullback to pivot </label></p>
  <p><input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>
```

Questions:

1) where do you put the hidden button? I have `<p>` tags because I want them on top of the other so do I put them all in the `<p>` tags? So would something like this work?

```
<p><label> <input type="hidden" name="30minRule" value="0">
             <input type="checkbox" name="30minRule" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST["30minRule"])) { echo 'checked="checked" '; } ?>>30 Min Rule</label></p>  
  <p><label> <input type="hidden" name="buyOnPocketPivot" value="0">
             <input type="checkbox" name="buyOnPocketPivot" value="1">Buy on Pocket Pivot</label></p>
```

2) On the topic of getting the info back from the database for checkbox status, I have the form linked to my php script will that be adequate for getting those values? They all go to and from the same location, or do I need something else?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: 1) Yes it works. They are hidden so it doesn't care where they are. As long they are in the form. 2) If you know which values are in your `form` you also know which one aren't submitted right? Why exactly do you want to pass the non-checked input boxes?

Comment: These are used to store rules so if the user unchecks a box and nothing is sent to the DB then its going to enforce the rule still. Thats bad.

Comment: In your php part you should have array that has all possible values as keys and values of those should be 0, than do populate that same array with values from _POST variable. #1 You can put hidden anywhere between form tags. On #2 question if you are asking if you can do getting and updating DB from 'TradingRules.php' sure you can. At begining of script check if ie $_POST['30minRule'] is set do update of DB, also having same name="30minRule" in hidden input and in checkbox  may not be what you intended to do.

Comment: the same name part I have seen both ways, probably not best to have the same name though huh?

Comment: I am going to ask what may be a dumb question:
    What if I do this:

    if (30min rule = 1){   set to 1 } else{ set to 0}; 

for each one? is that just too much work? Because if it doesnt come back as a 1 it will come back as nothing correct?

Comment: I decided not to use the route above because in an online sandbox it errored out whenever a variable isnt present that should be. So I am just going to try getting the 0 or 1 from the html, using different names for the hidden (.hidden) 0, or 1 for the checked value. Then in php storing either 0 or 1 in the database.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the value in PHP, it might be worth it to just make whatever is missing into a 0. This is easy enough with the `array_merge` function.

```
 $post_form = array_merge(array(
     '30minRule' => 0,
     'buyOnPocketPivot' => 0 // etc
 ), $_POST);
```